# exec() and system() commands does not work (php)

Tags: php

I am using wamp 2.2e.
I have tested the PHP on tha server and it works.

Now, I have a script called scriptA.py that I want to execute. 
I am not using safe mode, and in the php.ini the disable_functions line is empty.
Ok, so I tried:

```
 exec("C:\wamp\www\scriptA.py")
 exec('C:\wamp\www\scriptA.py')
 exec('C:\\wamp\\www\\scriptA.py')
```

same with system()...
tried with "`cmd /c`"..

none worked.

I also found a potential reason - maybe I need to set permmisions to the cmd using the CALC command, but I dont know what is my user, is it the computer name in control panel->system ?

please assist me

---

OK, there is a progress, now the browser shows me the errors:

```
Warning: exec() [<a href='function.exec'>function.exec</a>]: Unable to fork [C:\wamp\www\Telnetshutdown.py] in C:\wamp\www\index2.php on line 2
# Time Memory Function Location 
1 0.0005 362784 {main}( ) ..\index2.php:0 
2 0.0005 362912 exec ( ) ..\index2.php:2
```

( similar if i try with `system()` )  - does it help ?

Comment: u need to install python.compiler,then point the correct to the compiler

Comment: Maybe it's working but the user (operating system) is not you? Check your processes whether they are running.

Comment: I am the administrator. also the python is updated in the path. If I write 'C:\wamp\www\scriptA.py' in cmd the script works.

Comment: @user2162550 Your wamp isn't running as administrator. It may work if you change it so the service runs as Administrator.

Comment: It is likely that your default anonymous IIS user is not allowed access to the command line interpreter (exec())!

Comment: I updated the SYSTEM user (apache user) to maximum permissions with cmd. still does not work.. but the error notification is gone.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to invoke these via the Python executable as it's unlikely Python.exe is in the `PATH` of your `apache` user:

```
exec('C:\Python3\Python.exe C:\wamp\www\ScriptA.py');
```

There are several gripes with `exec` on Windows. You may find that refactoring your Python code to PHP is far less time consuming and more secure than giving `apache` user access to the whole disk like this.

Answer (score -1):

if you install ActiveState python, the installer associates files with .py extension to the python.exe program. Thus, all you need to do is double click on the file (in windows 2k (and possibly others), you can simply type the filename as is (i.e.) foo.py and the command shell knows to call the associated application)

http://www.activestate.com/Products/ActivePython/

EDIT;

This will solve your question:
http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/trouble_shooting/warning_exec_functionexec_unable_to_fork

Comment: I am not using IIS! the link is for IIS user. when i write the command, i get -  "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done."

Comment: The error message you are getting indicates that Analysis Server received the script containing a username that it cannot resolve. Basically somewhere in one of your security roles you have a member that is no longer part of the domain. Or it might be you are trying to use local user and machine name has changed or you are deploying to different machine.